# Can't enable custom Language Injection rule

Tags: sql, typescript, phpstorm, webstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

I try to add Language Injection rule to see SQL syntax highlighting inside TypeScript strings.
I can create rule, but can not set checkbox to enable this rule.
PhpStorm 2018.1

[image]

There are no ability to set checkbox for rules where `Scope` is `IDE`. Clicking directly on checkbox or on `Enable Selected Injections` button gives no result.

Comment: please attach a screenshot that would illustrate this

Comment: @Ástþór screenshot attached

Comment: Thanks. Most likely there's an error in your pattern, that's why the injection can't be enabled.

Comment: @Ástþór I do not do anything special:
(1) Press `Add` button
(2) Select `5. SQL Injection`
(3) `Language Injection Settings` window is opened. I just select `TypeScript` (or any other language) in Language ID dropdown.
That's all.

Comment: You would need to specify Places Pattern there, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2018.3/language-injection-settings-sql-injection.html. I don't have much of an experience with ts/js so you would have to google that